# Проблемы с функцией swap

Tags: c++, c

Я написал код для симметрии матрицы относительно побочной диагонали, на он ругается на

```
void swap(int *a, int *b) 
{
    int temp = a;
    *a = b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

А именно на

```
*a = b;
```

Вот сам код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b) 
{
    int temp = a;
    *a = b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int **p, n, i, j;
    printf_s("введите n\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    p = (int*)malloc(n*n * sizeof(int));
    srand(time(0));
    printf("\nОбычная:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            *(p+i*n+j) = rand() % 99;
            printf("%3d ", *(p + i * n + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



    printf("\n\nИзмененная:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if ((i + j) < (n - 1))
            {
                swap(&p[i][j], &p[n - j - 1][n - i - 1]);
            }
            printf("%3d ", *(p + i * n + j));

        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    _getch();
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так а что вы хотели сказать этим `int temp = a;`? Что вы хотели сказать `*a = b;`? У вас типы слева и справа не совпадают. В любом случае, ваша `int **p` матрица создаётся неправильно и в таком виде работать не будет. Написана мешанина ерунды.

Comment: Ну так вы присваиваете переменной типа `int` (разыменованное `a` *указатель*...) Так же как и переменной `temp` - тоже указатель. Кстати, неужто у вас ругается в одном случае и не ругается в другом?...

Comment: я  на форуме нашел эту функцию, но если к а добавить указатель всё равно не работает

Comment: можете написать как правильно должно быть

Comment: и temp тут вроде как просто фактическая переменная

Comment: @Alex Возле a и b должны быть звездочки.

Comment: мне пишет на строке int temp = *a; (Вызвано необработанное исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
a было 0x56.)

Comment: @Alex У вас p указатель на указатель, а Вы присваиваете ему обычный указатель

Comment: Тоесть надо в swap еще по указатель добавить?

Comment: @Alex Нужно при  обьявлении p убрать одну звездочку. А в цикле "изменения" писать как в цикле "обычная"

Comment: Вроде двумерный динамический массив через 2 указателя объявляется

Comment: он пишет что для swap слишком мало аргументов

Comment: @Alex Первый аргумент для swap будет (p + i * n + j). Второй сами напишите

Comment: спасибо, а то я тупил что-то

Comment: Двумерный массив неизвестного размера невозможно "объявить" (не считая VLA в C). Его можно только "построить вручную". И сделать это можно разными способами. У вас в коде наблюдается мешанина, надерганная из совершенно разных, никак друг с другом не совместимых способов.

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий вариант вашего метода swap:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b) 
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Однако, как заметили в комментариях выше у вас есть другие проблемы с приведенной программой.

Answer (score -1):

Перед свапом на проверять что свапаете (мало-ли что программисты понаписали). 
Метод на Xor не просит tmp переменную

```
void XORswap(int* a, int* b)
{
    if (a == b)
    {
        return;
    }

    *a ^= *b;
    *b ^= *a;
    *a ^= *b;

}
```

На крайняк (сарказм), не надо рожать костыль а дергать std

в

```
<algorithm>
```

есть

```
   std::swap
```